# DatagridView VB.Net, thread safety

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, winforms, datagridview, thread-safety

So i have this DataTable i have to show in a datagridview.
To do this i used to do the following line in the form_load

`Me.Datagridview1.datasource = DT`

It will work if i have to add a few rows, but when i add enough to make the scrollbar in the datagridview appear, it will freeze de program. No exceptions are thrown but my program will freeze and i think it is because im learning how to use threads.

Here i start listening another program that will send strings and i have to split them and put them into rows inside a datatable, and then show them.

```
Private Vstm As Stream
Dim tcp As New TcpClient
Dim DT As New DataTable("Acciones")
Dim Inter As New Interprete

Private Sub Conectar_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    tcp.Connect("192.168.1.143", 8050)
    Vstm = tcp.GetStream()
    Dim VtcpThd As New Thread(AddressOf LeerSocket)
    'Se arranca el subproceso.
    VtcpThd.Start()
End Sub
```

Here in LeerSocket ill do the reading

```
Private Sub LeerSocket()
        Dim VbufferDeLectura() As Byte
        VbufferDeLectura = New Byte(100) {}
        While True
            'Se queda esperando a que llegue algún mensaje.
            Vstm.Read(VbufferDeLectura, 0, VbufferDeLectura.Length)

            'Se evalúa que llega en la cabecera del mensaje.
            Me.Inter.interpretar(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(VbufferDeLectura))

        End While
    End Sub
```

Here it is the class interprete, that will try to understand the string.

```
Public Class Interprete

Property Codigo As String
Property Cotizacion As Integer
Property Cabecera As String

Private VAcciones As DataTable
Public Property Acciones() As DataTable
    Get
        Return VAcciones
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As DataTable)
        VAcciones = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Sub interpretar(Data As String)
    Me.Cabecera = Nothing
    Me.Codigo = Nothing
    Dim buff() As String = Split(Data, "!!")
    Dim arr() As String = Split(buff(0), "||")

    Me.Cabecera = arr(0)
    Me.Codigo = arr(1)
    Select Case Cabecera
        Case "COT"
            Cotizaciones(arr)
    End Select
End Sub
Public Sub Cotizaciones(M As String())
    Dim DR As DataRow = Acciones.NewRow
    Dim buffer(3) As Object
    buffer(0) = ""
    buffer(1) = 0
    buffer(2) = M(1)
    buffer(3) = M(2)
    DR.ItemArray = buffer
    Acciones.Rows.Add(DR)
End Sub
End Class
```

How can i use the datagridview safely? 
Also can you guys recomend any books for vb?

Comment: As LarsTech answered, you need to either `BeginInvoke` or `Invoke` when adding a new row to the `DataTable`. Creating new `DataRows` on the non-UI thread indirectly causes changes in the `DataGridView`, and it will lead to unexpected results. So you can't use a shared `DataTable`.

Answer (score 0):

You should invoke that data table action on the GUI thread:

```
Me.BeginInvoke(New Action(Sub()
                            Dim DR As DataRow = Acciones.NewRow
                            Dim buffer(3) As Object
                            buffer(0) = ""
                            buffer(1) = 0
                            buffer(2) = M(1)
                            buffer(3) = M(2)
                            DR.ItemArray = buffer
                            Acciones.Rows.Add(DR)
                          End Sub))
```